# Classic ASP bind input to variable

Tags: data-binding, forms, binding, asp-classic

I am more of a .Net guy, but the site I currently work on has some legacy Classic ASP pages lying around. In one of the forms we have a couple of hidden inputs that get set to variables created and set by some VBScript at the beginning of the page like so:

```
<input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<%= oReferer %>" />
```

That variable is set with the following VBScript:

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript" runat="server">
        dim oReferer
        dim origReferer, arrRefer1, arrRefer2
        origReferer = "self"

        'response.Write("referer - " & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
        'response.End()
        if not Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") = "" then 
            if not Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE") = "" then
                if not len(Request.Cookies("OrigReferer")) > 0 then
                    arrRefer1 = split(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"),"//")
                    if UBound(arrRefer1) > 0 then
                        arrRefer2 = split(arrRefer1(1), "/")
                        if UBound(arrRefer2) > 0 then
                            origReferer = arrRefer2(0)
                        end if
                    end if
                    Response.Cookies("OrigReferer") = origReferer
                    Response.Cookies("OrigReferer").Expires = DateAdd("d", 120, Date())
                else
                    oReferer = Request.Cookies("OrigReferer")
                end if 
            else
                oReferer = "no cookies"
            end if
        else
            oReferer = "self"
        end if
<script>
```

This code works all fine, most of the time. When I try using this code in a newer version of the form I am getting two issues. First the input itself does not get set at all. I am not sure why as the code does have a default so it should always at least be "self". Second issue is that the original code, not written by me, worked using <% oReferer %> to set the value. When I do that now I get a VBScript error, "type mismatch".

Like I said I am a .Net guy and solving this in .Net is not a problem. I don't know Classic ASP as well and I am stumped. I would love to change to .Net but can't for this particular form right now, so any help to figure this out would be great.

Comment: It should tell you what line the error occurred, can you highlight this in the code please?

Comment: `<% oReferer %>` probably needs to be `<%=oReferer %>` (ie with an equals sign)

Comment: Yep, you definitely need the `=` sign. Try appending something to the `oReferer = Request.Cookies("OrigReferer") & "**"` line value so see if you are executing this line. If the OrigReferer cookie is blank, `oReferer` will be blank (empty) too, and no value will be written in the `<% =oReferer %>` line.

Comment: Right now the code does use the = sign to set the value. Which fixed the error, but gave me the empty values.

The line it errors on when I don't use the = is the line for the input itself that I have in the original post. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the code of creating and setting oReferer, but some mismatch in setting it to the value. Almost like oReferer is not being seen as a string. 

Lastly, doing the Request.Cookies("OrigReferer") & "**" idea still gives me an empty value on the input. 

This issue seems really bizarre to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%
    dim oReferer
    dim origReferer, arrRefer1, arrRefer2
    origReferer = "self"

    if not Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") = "" then 
        if not Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE") = "" then
            if not len(Request.Cookies("OrigReferer")) > 0 then
                arrRefer1 = split(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"),"//")
                if UBound(arrRefer1) > 0 then
                    arrRefer2 = split(arrRefer1(1), "/")
                    if UBound(arrRefer2) > 0 then
                        origReferer = arrRefer2(0)
                    end if
                end if
                Response.Cookies("OrigReferer") = origReferer
                Response.Cookies("OrigReferer").Expires = DateAdd("d", 120, Date())

                ''// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                ''// The problems is that you are not 
                ''// setting the oReferer variable here
                ''// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            else
                oReferer = Request.Cookies("OrigReferer")
            end if 
        else
            oReferer = "no cookies"
        end if
    else
        oReferer = "self"
    end if

    response.write "----------<br>"
    response.write "oReferer=" + oReferer
 %>
```

Comment: I added a simple oReferer = Request.Cookies("OrigReferer") like you suggested, and I still see the same behavior. The hidden field is not getting set at all. I can see the cookie getting set when it is supposed to, but something keeps it from getting into the hidden field. Is there an alternative to using the <%= oReferer %> code?

Comment: I found a solution to the issue by using <%= Request.Cookies("OrigReferer") %> and always sending the info to the cookie from now on. The best I can figure is that the value stored in oReferer is being lost between the code setting it, and the call to get it.

Comment: The point is that the code have several ways to came up with an empty `oReferer` or an empty `Request.Cookies("OrigReferer")`

Comment: The problem I was having wasn't around an empty oReferer. It turned out to be much simpler, and way more annoying. The variable oReferer is created within the <script> tag, and it dies within that tag. When I call it further down in the <%= %> tag, it doesn't exist anymore. If anyone knows how to persist that variable, other than session states or cookies it'd be a huge help.

Comment: If you create the variable outside any `sub` the variable has the entire page scope. To be sure you are using only declared variables put `<% Option Explicit %>` on the top of the page, right after `<%@ Language=VBScript %>`